# "Add connection" dialog does not show all databases in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, database-connection, connection-string

This is when connecting to establish a datasource connection using "Server Explorer" [clicking the drum with a green plus icon]. What happens is it does show the system databases but not the databases that we imported from another system. These databases are in separate directory in SQL Management Studio.

Earlier when I connecting to the same database, I was getting an error msg that the database does not have owner. I dont get that msg anymore. But these databases are still not populated in drop down box.

---

Second I have trouble connecting to the database from the project where they were originally developed in. We did change something that means we migrated databases from the production version into the developer environment. Does anybody know how to fix that as well?

### update: Solution

Let me answer it myself...

1. Not all databases were showing because there were three databases engine running on the machine. The user databases were imported into the wrong server not the EXPRESS one, hence the database were not showing in  express server.
2. As for connectivity errors, obviously if there is no database, no connection can be established. I am getting more targeted errors now regarding the connection though.

Thanks Justin.

Thank you!

Comment: the correct way to answer your own question is to [create an answer yourself and accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to) after the delay. On this way people see that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer it myself...

1. Not all databases were showing because there were three databases engine running on the machine. The user databases were imported into the wrong server not the EXPRESS one that I was using.
2. As for connectivity errors, obviously if there is no database, no connection can be established. I am getting more targeted errors now regarding the connection though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having an issue with ownership of the database.  I would log into Sql Server Manager, and check the security settings on your databases - does the user you are logging in with have dbo?